# Android: Only Acclerometer reading is shown,Gyroscope sensor is not reading

Tags: android, android-sensors

I tried the code for gyroscope from [this link](http://www.41post.com/3745/programming/android-acessing-the-gyroscope-sensor-for-simple-applications)

The problem is it will show values only when the sensor is Accelerometer.
I tried to display all sensors using

```
List<Sensor> sensors = sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
    for (Sensor sensor : sensors) {
        Log.d("Sensors", "" + sensor.getName());
    }
```

and i got the result

```
12-02 15:44:20.816: D/Sensors(15757): AMI304 3-axis Magnetic Field sensor
12-02 15:44:20.816: D/Sensors(15757): ADXL345 3-axis Accelerometer
12-02 15:44:20.817: D/Sensors(15757): bh1620fvc Light Sensor
12-02 15:44:20.817: D/Sensors(15757): MPU3000  gyroscope Sensor
12-02 15:44:20.817: D/Sensors(15757): Rotation Vector Sensor
12-02 15:44:20.817: D/Sensors(15757): Gravity Sensor
12-02 15:44:20.817: D/Sensors(15757): Linear Acceleration Sensor
12-02 15:44:20.817: D/Sensors(15757): Orientation Sensor
12-02 15:44:20.817: D/Sensors(15757): Corrected Gyroscope Sensor
```

So the gyroscope is there.Then why accelerometer only is showing values?
Pls help me

**Edit:**

I am using HCL ME Y3 tablet with android 4.0.4

Code

```
package fortyonepost.com.ag;//Created by: DimasTheDriver on Apr/27/2010. Available at: 

http://www.41post.com/?p=3745

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AccessGyroscope extends Activity implements SensorEventListener
{
//a TextView
private TextView tv;
//the Sensor Manager
private SensorManager sManager;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //get the TextView from the layout file
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    //get a hook to the sensor service
    sManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
}

//when this Activity starts
@Override
protected void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
    /*register the sensor listener to listen to the gyroscope sensor, use the 
     * callbacks defined in this class, and gather the sensor information as  
     * quick as possible*/
    sManager.registerListener(this, sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}

//When this Activity isn't visible anymore
@Override
protected void onStop() 
{
    //unregister the sensor listener
    sManager.unregisterListener(this);
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) 
{
    //Do nothing
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
{
    //if sensor is unreliable, return void
    if (event.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE)
    {
        return;
    }

    //else it will output the Roll, Pitch and Yawn values
    tv.setText("Orientation X (Roll) :"+ Float.toString(event.values[2]) +"\n"+
               "Orientation Y (Pitch) :"+ Float.toString(event.values[1]) +"\n"+
               "Orientation Z (Yaw) :"+ Float.toString(event.values[0]));
}
}
```

**Edit 2**

I tried the same code in Galaxy tab. It's working. But i want it to work here also.
The function `onSensorChanged` is being called only for Acceleromter. It is not being called for any other sensor.Why?
Am i missing anything in the tablet settings?anything to be done to enable gyrosocpe?

Comment: Have you downloaded the project and run as it is or you've modified your source? If so, please post your code. This project runs fine on my phone.

Comment: i run it without modification.but no reading is coming.

Comment: Maybe OS can't see hardware on kernel level?

Comment: Please post your code anyway, there must be some issue there. Also, what phone are you testing it on?

Comment: Log your `event.sensor.getType()` in the onSensorChanged and see which kind of sensors do you receive.  Also maybe this is happening because it returns accuracy unreliable. Make a calibration of the gyroscope first and try again.

Comment: The `onSensorChanged` function is not even called for other sensors.works only for acclerometer

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. The only thing that comes to mind is that in onSensorChanged, event.accuracy is always UNRELIABLE on your device. Try adding Log.d("MYTAG", "Accuracy unreliable") to see if that's the case:

```
//if sensor is unreliable, return void
if (event.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE)
{
    Log.d("MYTAG", "Accuracy unreliable");
    return;
}
```

Please also note that Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION is deprecated as of API level 8. Use SensorManager.getOrientation() or Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE instead. Check the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-gyro).

Comment: he does not want to use the orientation... the accuracy is refering to something else if I understood corectly. Check the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH

Comment: He's running the project from the link he provided, which in turn uses TYPE_ORIENTATION, and his question was why it's not displaying any values. That same project runs on my phone fine. Now if the sensor accuracy, which can be checked with event.accuracy, as specified in the docs you provided is SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE, his code for displaying values will not even run.

Comment: `Log.d("MYTAG", "Accuracy unreliable");` is not logging. The function `onSensorChanged` is not even called for Gyro,is called only for Accelerometer

Comment: Looks like something to do with your device then. Install any gyroscope app from Google Play and see if it works. Also, try experimenting with different delays and even TYPE_GYROSCOPE.